# Quasar - Pinia getter returning wrong value while using local storage

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, quasar, pinia

I'm using LocalStorage to persist the bearer token value in pinia store. Everything works as supposed if a page refresh hasn't occurred while using the application.

If a page refresh occurred, getToken getter is returning a wrong value.
Issue I'm having is during the logout action, more precisely with action setToken.

```
state: () => ({
    user: null,
    token: null
}),

getters: {
    getUser: (state) => state.user,
    getToken: (state) => {
        if (state.token) return state.token
        return LocalStorage.getItem('token') || null
    },
},

actions: {
    ...
    async logout () {
        try {
            await api.get('/logout')
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }

        this.user = null
        await this.setToken(null)
    },

    async setToken (token) {
        this.token = token
        if (token) {
            LocalStorage.set('token', token)
        } else {
            LocalStorage.remove('token')
        }
        console.log('local storage:')
        console.log(LocalStorage.getItem('token'))

        console.log('state:')
        console.log(this.token)

        console.log('getter:')
        console.log(this.getToken)
    }
}
```

Looking at the console log, you can see that getter is returning a token, even though it's set to null in state and removed from local storage.

Looks like getters are being cached somehow when they use LocalStorage, or something else I'm not aware of.

Console log results when logging out:

```
without refreshing the page:
local storage: null
state: null
getter: null

with refreshing the page before calling an action:
local storage: null
state: null
getter: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciO...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's unknown how LocalStorage works. Built-in doesn't have set and remove methods. There's no distinction between null and "null" string in the output. The console shouldn't be used as a reliable way to debug apps. You can check the contents of LS in devtools in realtime to confirm it works as expected. If this doesn't help, please, provide a way to reproduce the problem